# Memory leak attaching multiple photos in MFMailComposerViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, cgimage, alasset

I am trying to attach multiple photos in a `MailComposerViewController` and I am using `ALAssetPickerViewController` to pick multiple photos. I have an `NSMutableArray`, which contains reference of selected assets. I am implementing a `for loop` which is enumerating over `array` of selected assets to get `NSData` of `UIImage` and `UIImage` is initialized with `CGImageRef`.
Code is as written below:

```
@autoreleasepool
{
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Test";
    NSString *messageBody = @"IOS programming is so fun!";
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc@gmail.com", nil];

    MFMailComposeViewController *tempmcvc = nil;
    tempmcvc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    tempmcvc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [tempmcvc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [tempmcvc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
    [tempmcvc setToRecipients:toRecipents];
    tempmcvc.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    tempmcvc.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    for (AlAsset *assets in SelectedAssetsarray) 
    {
        @autoreleasepool
        {
            UIImage *attachImagTemp = nil;
            NSData *myData = nil;
            CGImageRef iref = [assets.defaultRepresentation fullScreenImage];
            NSString *nameOfImgTemp;
            attachImagTemp = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
            nameOfImgTemp = assets2.defaultRepresentation.filename;                      
            myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation (attachImagTemp, 1.0);
            [tempmcvc addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:nameOfImgTemp];

            myData = nil;
            attachImagTemp = nil;
            iref = nil;
            nameOfImgTemp = nil;
            ALAsset *_temp = assets2;
            _temp = nil;

        }
    }
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    [self presentModalViewController:tempmcvc animated:YES]
});
```

Each asset I am attaching hardly is of 2 MB, but memory is constantly decreasing I am     unable to release the memory properly; some memory is leaking please help to find the leak.

Comment: I see that you don't release tempmcvc. Am I right?

Comment: try releasing `CGImageRef` by `CGImageRelease`. It might help you. Coz  we have to release `CGImageRef` object explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

Try releasing attachment image with following code  **CGImageRelease(attachImagTemp);** to release cache memory instead setting it as nil.

Also release tempmcvc object as suggested by Avi if you have not used ARC.

Comment: `CGImageRelease` is for releasing `CGImageRef`, not for release `UIImage *`.